# Spring Boot service shuts down automatically in idle or after service too many requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I have "my-app" spring boot service which is based on v2.1.4.RELEASE. This service acts as controller to all my microservice. I am using eureka to register every other microservices along with this my-app ( controller ). I am experiencing some unusual behvaviour from this service.

1. In idle mode it automatically stops responding.
2. When serving too many requests it stops responding after some time.

   After digging into logs I have found following stack trace:

```
01-07-2021 09:32:19.675 [AsyncResolver-bootstrap-executor-0] INFO  c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver.getClusterEndpoints - Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
01-07-2021 09:32:20.057 [Thread-13] INFO  c.n.l.PollingServerListUpdater.run - Shutting down the Executor Pool for PollingServerListUpdater
01-07-2021 09:32:20.058 [Thread-9] INFO  o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry.deregister - Unregistering application MY-APP with eureka with status DOWN
01-07-2021 09:32:20.058 [Thread-9] WARN  c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.notify - Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1625112140058, current=DOWN, previous=UP]
01-07-2021 09:32:20.059 [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] INFO  c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register - DiscoveryClient_MY-APP/MY-APP:9c84f59eab3882519f16fd7be15bb138: registering service...
01-07-2021 09:32:20.061 [Thread-9] INFO  c.n.u.c.ShutdownEnabledTimer.cancel - Shutdown hook removed for: NFLoadBalancer-PingTimer-CALLMASTERS
01-07-2021 09:32:20.063 [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] INFO  c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register - DiscoveryClient_MY-APP/MY-APP:9c84f59eab3882519f16fd7be15bb138 - registration status: 204
01-07-2021 09:32:20.073 [Thread-9] INFO  c.n.u.c.ShutdownEnabledTimer.cancel - Exception caught (might be ok if at shutdown)
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
            at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.remove(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:82)
            at java.lang.Runtime.removeShutdownHook(Runtime.java:239)
            at com.netflix.util.concurrent.ShutdownEnabledTimer.cancel(ShutdownEnabledTimer.java:70)
            at com.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer.cancelPingTask(BaseLoadBalancer.java:613)
            at com.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer.shutdown(BaseLoadBalancer.java:864)
            at com.netflix.loadbalancer.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer.shutdown(DynamicServerListLoadBalancer.java:285)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.invokeCustomDestroyMethod(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:337)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:271)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:571)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:543)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1055)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:504)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1026)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:975)
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.1.4.RELEASE
         
    
    com.akash
    my-controller
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    my-controller
    
        1.8

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- new dependency -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.ribbon</groupId>
        <artifactId>ribbon-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<description>core Controller</description>
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=MY-APP-CONTROLLER
port.no=8585
host.name=localhost
logging.config=configuration/logback.xml
server.ip=http://my-app.eureka.com/eureka/
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://my- 
app.eureka.com/eureka
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=510MB
server.tomcat.max-threads=500
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
```

Is there any configuration needs to be done here?

Thanks for the help in advance! :)

Comment: can you show both the pom dependencies of eureka and your application.properties?

Comment: @L_Cleo I have updated question with pom and application.properties

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a dependency version problem

Try adding this to your pom

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Greenwich.SR6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then remove all versions specified inside the spring cloud dependencies. For example

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @L_Cleo . This is working for me. Will be monitoring for some more time. But could you please explain what is the purpose of adding the above block ?

Comment: So basically you were having incompatible spring-cloud dependencies versions with your spring parent version. While it might not be a drastic incompatibility, it might still cause some bugs like in your case. The dependency management block is just a way to let automatically handle the versioning of the spring-cloud dependencies in this case. So all spring-cloud dependencies will refer to that specific pom within the dependency management tag

Comment: okay Got it. Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: If it solved your problem, kindly mark it as the correct answer to help both me and other users with the same issue :)